# "Whom of which", a valid expression?

Tags: grammar, errors, whom

I recently encountered this expression and I'm pretty much stumped. People seem to be using it in place of "who". Example:

> [...] they were developed by non-medical professionals **whom of which** have applied their skills to help solve a health care / medical problem they had faced.

Another example:

> As well as Dave, special thanks goes to the 'Girls in Pink' for providing a high service throughout the whole day, as well as club chairman, Bob Thomsett and Chrissie **whom of which** manned the kitchen which was busy all day.

I can't quite wrap my head around the expression, but I figured it might be one of the many idiosyncrasies of the English language. Is this a valid expression or some newfangled bastardisation?

Comment: They're wrong.  "*Who*" is all you need and what you want.  And there's more wrong with those sentences besides "*whom of which*".

Comment: This is fascinating. Google estimates half a million uses (which to be sure probably a tenth or hundredth that number) since the 1980s, mostly in the new century, and it has actually made it into a couple of dozen books. In all of them it simply means *who* (relative). My best guess is that it's a far-fetched hypercorrection like "gave it to he and I" by people trying to emulate "sophisticated" speech. I'm eager to see any answers about its origin.

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of the Google hits seem to be false positives (dictionaries listing "whose, of whom, of which", etc.). If you add -"of whom of which" to the query only 6800 results remain.

Comment: The [webpage for the 2nd quote](http://www.seafordtownfc.org.uk/youth/index.htm?news.htm~main) (June 2012 entry) also says (Nov 2012 entry)  “Seaford ran out 2-1 victors with goals coming from Joel Tucker and Toby Hunter, **whom of both** have scored plenty already this season”

Comment: I think this "construction" is so far removed from "credible" it's simply Too Localised. Searching Google Books for *whom of which were/are/was/is/have* I did manage to find half-a-dozen instances, but what does that mean? There seem to be at least as many for the equally gibberish ***whose** of which were/are/etc.*.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I'd upvote you if I could! I'm glad my bewilderment was not unfounded. I've also found [this thread](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/159982-using-whom.html) on usingenglish.com that supports the view that the expression is nonsensical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a grammatical mistake and no definitive answer could be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a valid expression.  It's simply bad English